# How to import data file from the S3 bucket into the Sagemaker notebook?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, dataloader

I have npz files that I want to import for my model training.
Below is the code I have tried.

```
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

# To List 5 files in your accessible bucket
#fs.ls('s3://input_data/train_npz/')[:5]

# open it directly
with fs.open(f's3://input_data/train_npz/0.npz') as f:
    display(Image.open(f))
```

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> ```
>
> last)  in 
> 7
> 8 # open it directly
> ----> 9 with fs.open(f's3://input_data/train_npz/0.npz')
> as f:
> 10     display(Image.open(f))
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py in open(self,
> path, mode, block_size, cache_options, **kwargs)
> 980                 autocommit=ac,
> 981                 cache_options=cache_options,
> --> 982                 **kwargs,
> 983             )
> 984             if not ac and "r" not in mode:
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py in _open(self,
> path, mode, block_size, acl, version_id, fill_cache, cache_type,
> autocommit, requester_pays, **kwargs)
> 543             cache_type=cache_type,
> 544             autocommit=autocommit,
> --> 545             requester_pays=requester_pays,
> 546         )
> 547
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py in **init**(self,
> s3, path, mode, block_size, acl, version_id, fill_cache,
> s3_additional_kwargs, autocommit, cache_type, requester_pays)    1822
> self.version_id = self.details.get("VersionId")    1823
> super().**init**(
> -> 1824             s3, path, mode, block_size, autocommit=autocommit, cache_type=cache_type    1825         )    1826         self.s3 =
> self.fs  # compatibility
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py in
> **init**(self, fs, path, mode, block_size, autocommit, cache_type, cache_options, **kwargs)    1302         if mode == "rb":    1303
> if not hasattr(self, "details"):
> -> 1304                 self.details = fs.info(path)    1305             self.size = self.details["size"]    1306             self.cache =
> caches[cache_type](
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py in
> wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 86     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
> 87         self = obj or args[0]
> ---> 88         return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
> 89
> 90     return wrapper
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py in sync(loop,
> func, timeout, *args, **kwargs)
> 67         raise FSTimeoutError
> 68     if isinstance(result[0], BaseException):
> ---> 69         raise result[0]
> 70     return result[0]
> 71
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py in
> _runner(event, coro, result, timeout)
> 23         coro = asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout=timeout)
> 24     try:
> ---> 25         result[0] = await coro
> 26     except Exception as ex:
> 27         result[0] = ex
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py in _info(self,
> path, bucket, key, refresh, version_id)    1062                 else:
> 1063                     try:
> -> 1064                         out = await self._simple_info(path)    1065                     except PermissionError:    1066
>
> ## If the permissions aren't enough for scanning a prefix
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py in
> _simple_info(self, path)
> 982             Delimiter="/",
> 983             MaxKeys=1,
> --> 984             **self.req_kw,
> 985         )
> 986         # This method either can return the info blob for the object if it
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py in _call_s3(self,
> method, *akwarglist, **kwargs)
> 235
> 236     async def _call_s3(self, method, *akwarglist, **kwargs):
> --> 237         await self.set_session()
> 238         s3 = await self.get_s3(kwargs.get("Bucket"))
> 239         method = getattr(s3, method)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/s3fs/core.py in
> set_session(self, refresh, kwargs)
> 376
> 377         conf = AioConfig(**config_kwargs)
> --> 378         self.session = aiobotocore.AioSession(**self.kwargs)
> 379
> 380         for parameters in (config_kwargs, self.kwargs, init_kwargs, client_kwargs):
>
> AttributeError: module 'aiobotocore' has no attribute 'AioSession'

Can anyone let me know where I made the mistake or how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`s3fs` needs credetials, see [here](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#credentials), I think you have to provide the credentials for the bucket using one of the methods listed in the doc I linked. However there are many other ways to read `s3` files into a sagemaker notebook, take a look [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-read-data-files-on-s3-from-amazon-sagemaker-f288850bfe8f) for example.